# Jquery radio button code works in Chrome, but not Firefox or IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Having problems with the following code. It works fine in a Chrome browser but not Firefox or IE. Basically what I'm trying to do is alter an image to show either rounded or square corners depending on what the user selects from radio button options.

Here is my code:

```
// set corner style  
    $(".productOptionViewRadio").click(function(){    
       var span_html = $(event.target).next().html();       

       if (span_html == 'Rounded') {
          $('.ProductThumbImage').css('border-radius','15px');             
          $('.ProductThumbImage img').css('border-radius','15px');
       }
       if (span_html == 'Square') { 
          $('.ProductThumbImage').css('border-radius','0px');   
          $('.ProductThumbImage img').css('border-radius','0px');
       }
    });
```

HTML code source I'm working with:

```
<div class="productAttributeValue">
    <div class="productOptionViewRadio">
        <ul>
         <li>
             <label>
             <input type="radio" class="validation" name="attribute[238]" value="125" checked="checked"/>
             <span class="name">Rounded</span>
         </label>
         </li>
             <li>
                 <label>
             <input type="radio" class="validation" name="attribute[238]" value="126"/>
             <span class="name">Square</span>
        </label>
             </li>
    </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the first two lines of your jQuery to this:

```
$(".productOptionViewRadio input").click(function () {
    var span_html = $(this).next().html();
```

Live demo showing the correct span content being alerted: http://jsfiddle.net/Czk2H/